# Recoverable Error while creating Custom query in collecition.php under resource model in magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, code-generation

I have created a custom query in Model/ResourceModel/Notification/Collection.php file but now it shows an error in admin:

> Recoverable Error: Argument 5 passed to `Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Notification\Collection::__construct()` must be an instance of `Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime`, instance of `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager` given, called in app/code/Namespace/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Notification/Grid/Collection.php on line 54 and defined in app/code/Namespace/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Notification/Collection.php on line 61

Comment: can  you share you custom query code?

Comment: Check out rules for overriding core classes constructs http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92480/697 and remember to clear `var/generation`